# Alternative to visibility:hidden

Tags: css, visibility

I have a question on using CSS in order to **hide a row in a questionnaire** (problem occurs more than 20 times, so unfortunately difficult to just adjust just the structure of the questionnaire):
**How can I hide an HTML table row  so that it takes up no space (unlike: "visibility:hidden")?**

I look for an **alternative command to "visibility: collapse"** (hide row (unlike: "*visibility:hide*") but keep impact on layout (keep rowspan + colspan in contrast to "*display:none*") that works in all browsers including Chrome and IE.
Is there any **alternative** that would solve my problem?

I have added a **link** to the page that causes my problem for your reference:

http://ww2.unipark.de/uc/hollnder_Goethe_Universit__t_Fra/4568/ospe.php?SES=ce4b3db51563762d1d5b1c27c3598dbc&syid=243842&sid=243843&act=start&preview_mode=1

*(Code: 80a4231323d632d5 if asked: "Bitte geben Sie Ihre gültigen Zugangsdaten ein")*

I added the **row with the item scales (occuring always on top)** always also below the subtitle in order to  solve the problem of shifting buttons for the statements below (currently have the problem of shifting buttons for questions 1 and 2 - problem is fixed for question 3 but I cannot get rid of the additional space below the subtitle).

To solve my problem, I have tried to add the below 3 different codes in a **separate CSS file** which one can use to adjust the style of the questionnaire:

---

```
.nameq_2610826 ul.head.odd.i4 {opacity: 0; position: absolute; z-index: 10; top: 0; left: 0;}
```

-> FIRST QUESTION: SPACE IS ELIMINATED VIA `font-size:0px` BUT THIS WAY ALSO THE LAYOUT IS DISTROYED

```
.nameq_2612760 ul.head.odd.i4 {display: none; border-bottom:none}
```

-> SECOND QUESTION: SPACE IS ELIMINATED VIA `display:none` BUT THIS WAY ALSO THE LAYOUT IS DISTROYED

```
.nameq_2612762 ul.head.odd.i4 {visibility: collapse; border-bottom:none}
```

-> THIRD QUESTION: LAYOUT OF ITEMS BELOW IS KEPT IN THE RIGHT WAY BUT I CANNOT GET RID OF THE SPACE AS WITH COMMAND `Visibility:COLLAPSE` IN FIREFOX

An alternative way to solve the problem might be to make sure that the design is not destroyed by the usage of subtitles. In fact, I use the additional row with the item scales just to make sure that the buttons below follow the same layout as above the subtitles.

Any solution to my problem would be super helpful.

Comment: .class{ display:none }?

Comment: No.@rorypicko He says not in the question.

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/video-screencasts/142-hiding-things-with-css/

Comment: I'm unable to see the given example URL now.

Comment: Thanks guys! Unfortunately in the video I do not find a solution to remove the space below the subheader.
Best, Christian

Comment: I updated the URL which hopefully works now. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

One alternative to

```
visibility: hidden;
```

is

```
opacity: 0;
```

That will make the element completely transparent.

If you then want to move it out of the way so it occupies no space on the page, you might try something like:

```
position: absolute;
z-index: 12;
top: 0;
left: 0;
```

Comment: Thanks Rounin!
With "Opacity: 0" I am also able to remove the wording but unfortunately I cannot get rid of the space of the row below the subheader (also when setting height:0). 
Best, Christian

Comment: I have added some more to the post above. Please confirm if this now works as you wish it to.

Comment: Thank you! 
I changed the CSS command for the first question to: 
.nameq_2610826 ul.head.odd.i4 {opacity: 0; position: absolute; z-index: 10; top: 0; left: 0;} You can check the link to see how it looks like.
Unfortunately, this distroys again the layout of the buttons below - I think this happens when I change position from static to absolute? 
Any idea? Thanks very much!

Comment: Unless I am reading it wrong, your button layout messes up every time you remove the element, no? Regardless of your approach, it seems that each time you either have a gap (where you don't want one) or a messed-up layout. Have you ever reduced the gap to nothing and not had a messed-up layout? If not, I'd suggest that it's removing the gap (which I understand you're trying to do) which is messing up the layout.

Comment: Also, please can you post your code? It's very difficult for all of us trying to help you, when all we can do is try to imagine your markup. All that happens when I click on the link is I am requested: _"Bitte geben Sie Ihre gültigen Zugangsdaten ein"_ - and I don't have a valid passcode to enter.

Comment: Hi Rounin,
Sorry - I changed the link (http://ww2.unipark.de/uc/hollnder_Goethe_Universit__t_Fra/4568/ospe.php?SES=ce4b3db51563762d1d5b1c27c3598dbc&syid=243842&sid=243843&act=start&preview_mode=1). This happens when I change something in CSS. I hope this works now! 
You read it completely right: I either have a gap or a messed-up layout. The only chance for me to have a working layout was until now to use the command "visibility:collapse" which does not work in many browsers. This makes me search for an alternative.
Many thanks and best, Christian

Answer (score 4):

Try `display: none;`
this will render the element with 0 height and width
and also invisible semantically.

Comment: Thank you Itamar!
While  "display:none" successfully removes the unnecessary space, it unfortunately does distroy the layout and changes the position of the buttons below (quesiton 2 of the above link is created via "display:none):
Best, Christian

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried overflow: hidden along with a height of 0?

Comment: Thank you St.G!
Unfortunately, using height or line-height does not make any change to the space that I see. The only way to change the space was reducing font-size which then impacts the position of the buttons below. 
Best, Christian

Answer (score 0):

I am wondering: You write about a HTML table, but there is no table in your code, it's all `ul`and `li` elements, and other stuff (input, labels etc.) inside them (?).

So I would recommend to actually *use* tables, however not with `<table>`, `<tr>`and `<td>` tags, but with `<div>` tags instead, which get their table styling trough CSS, like `display: table`, `display: table-row` and `display: table-cell`. These are much more flexible concerning styling (CSS) and also responsivity (although I don't know if you are after that).

It's quite a bit of work to rebuild the whole page like that, but I think it could help you.

Comment: This is really an **extended** comment, not an answer.

Comment: Many thanks, Johannes! 
Unfortunately, I am a bit limited via the questionnaire tool that I can only adjust by using an external CSS file. So unfortunately would be difficult to rebuild stuff. 
Best, Christian